# Launching two spring boot apps at the same time using maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat, server

I have two spring boot apps with their own `application.properties`.

One is in my `src/main/resources` as `application.properties` and the other as  `test.properties` in `src/test/resources`.

I want it so that when I launch my spring boot app in main, it also simultaneously launches the spring boot app in my test. I want to do this in Maven command line but I was also wondering if it is possible to do in Spring Boot as well, perhaps programmatically?

The spring boot apps are running on ***localhost*** but two different ports.

The one in main is running on `localhost:28433` and the other on `localhost:9119`.

I have tried running this ***mvn command***:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=9119""--server.port=28433"
```

I am not sure this works though.. when I run it in my terminal it outputs this:

```
t.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 28433 (http)
2019-08-12 15:25:51.641  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-12 15:25:51.641  INFO 37469 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-08-12 15:25:51.649  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/asluborski/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-08-12 15:25:51.707  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-12 15:25:51.707  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 934 ms
2019-08-12 15:25:51.731  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet messageDispatcherServlet mapped to [/nulogix/ws/*]
2019-08-12 15:25:51.732  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-08-12 15:25:51.735  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-12 15:25:51.735  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-12 15:25:51.735  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-12 15:25:51.736  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-12 15:25:51.760 DEBUG 37469 --- [           main] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : billing.engine.address=127.0.0.1
2019-08-12 15:25:51.760 DEBUG 37469 --- [           main] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : billing.engine.port=9119
2019-08-12 15:25:51.760 DEBUG 37469 --- [           main] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : Using http://127.0.0.1:9119
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/Users/asluborski/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-08-12 15:25:52.037 DEBUG 37469 --- [           main] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.api.version=0.97
2019-08-12 15:25:52.038 DEBUG 37469 --- [           main] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.core.version=0.97
2019-08-12 15:25:52.038 DEBUG 37469 --- [           main] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.core.name=Nulogix_Patient_Responsibility
2019-08-12 15:25:52.039 DEBUG 37469 --- [           main] c.n.b.ws.endpoint.GetVersionEndPoint     : billing.engine.api.version=0.97
2019-08-12 15:25:52.184  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-12 15:25:52.398  INFO 37469 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 28433 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-12 15:25:52.402  INFO 37469 --- [           main] com..billing.App                  : Started App in 1.995 seconds (JVM running for 9.911)
```

It says above that it is using `127.0.0.1:9119` but it seems to only start my main App but not my test App which is specifically called `mockServerApp` so I do not think it is doing what I want...

How do I launch these simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm can't tell what mockServerApp is being used for, but I don't think bootRun handles multiple applications or even scans your test classes.

If you want to mock an external dependency for unit testing purposes, you should wrap the calls in a proxy class of some sort and use @MockBean to inject a mock instance.

If you want to deploy a stub external dependency for development purposes, you could create a separate project for the stub as a parent directory that would invoke maven on startup. You could even implement the mock in a different framework or language.

The most straightforward option, though would be to write a shell script that [launches and kills both services](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/08/24/start-stop-bash-background-process/).

For specifying the ports, in the application.properties of each set the server.port to be an environment variable:

primary application.conf:

```
server.port=${MY_APP_PORT:28433}
```

mock application.conf:

```
server.port=${MOCK_APP_PORT:9119}
```

For launching external dependencies in integration tests, check out [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/)